# WPF Datacontext Sql Update, Delete, Insert

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I want to create a WPF Application with a SQL-Connection to a Database. For my test application I'm using the NorthWind database. I followed this [Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428.aspx) on MSDN to create the DataContext class and the entity classes for my Application. I also created the object datasources for the entity "Customers". After adding the datasource to the MainWindow.xaml using Drag & Drop it created automatically a DataGrid.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationDataGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationDataGridTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customerViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Customer}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="customerOrderViewSource" Source="{Binding Order, Source={StaticResource customerViewSource}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource customerOrderViewSource}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkGray" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="customerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerViewSource}}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="boolColumn" Binding="{Binding Bool}" Header="Bool" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="cityColumn" Binding="{Binding City}" Header="City" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="companyNameColumn" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Header="Company Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contactNameColumn" Binding="{Binding ContactName}" Header="Contact Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="contactTitleColumn" Binding="{Binding ContactTitle}" Header="Contact Title" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="countryColumn" Binding="{Binding Country}" Header="Country" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerIDColumn" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="Customer ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="faxColumn" Binding="{Binding Fax}" Header="Fax" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Phone" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="postalCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding PostalCode}" Header="Postal Code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="regionColumn" Binding="{Binding Region}" Header="Region" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="orderDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="orderIDColumn" Binding="{Binding OrderID}" Header="Order ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="customerIDColumn1" Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="Customer ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="employeeIDColumn" Binding="{Binding EmployeeID}" Header="Employee ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="orderDateColumn" Header="Order Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding OrderDate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="requiredDateColumn" Header="Required Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding RequiredDate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="shippedDateColumn" Header="Shipped Date" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding ShippedDate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipViaColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipVia}" Header="Ship Via" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="freightColumn" Binding="{Binding Freight}" Header="Freight" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipNameColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipName}" Header="Ship Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipAddressColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipAddress}" Header="Ship Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipCityColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipCity}" Header="Ship City" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipRegionColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipRegion}" Header="Ship Region" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipPostalCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipPostalCode}" Header="Ship Postal Code" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="shipCountryColumn" Binding="{Binding ShipCountry}" Header="Ship Country" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,8" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="buttonSave_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonTest" Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,90,8" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="buttonTest_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private NorthWindDataContext northWindDataContext = new NorthWindDataContext();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource customerViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("customerViewSource")));
        customerViewSource.Source = northWindDataContext.Customers;
    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            northWindDataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The data are displayed fine, but if I try to update, delete or insert a record the changes are not commited to the database and if I check the values during the debugging the values are updated, deleted or inserted, but if I restart the application the changes havn't been saved. 
The behavior is not only with the NorthWind database but also with all other databases that I have tested.

Comment: I dont see how this is a `XAML` problem if you have the data right in the debugger bevore submitting it. Maybe focus more on the `SubmitChanges()`.

Comment: @Peter I think you're right. I tested the same with a WindowsForms Application and I've got the same problem.

Comment: Where is your database located? If you are using a local database, check if there is a database file in the *output* folder of the application, i.e. bin/Debug or bin/Release. You are probably overwriting this one on each build.

Comment: @mm8 Thank you, I changed the storage location of the database file and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a local database, you should make sure that the database file in the output folder of the application, i.e. bin/Debug or bin/Release is not getting overwritten on each build.

In other words, you need to make sure that you are writing to the same database file on each run.